# how to apply options for the functions using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a functions like this

```
def add(x,y):
    print x+y

def square(a):
    print a**2
```

Now I am defining linux commands(options) for this functions using argparse.

I tried with this code

```
import argparse
# Create Parser and Subparser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example ArgumentParser")
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(help="commands")

# Make Subparsers
add_parser = subparser.add_parser('--add', help="add func")
add_parser.add_argument("x",type=float,help='first number')
add_parser.add_argument("y",type=float,help='second number')
add_parser.set_defaults(func='add')

square_parser = subparser.add_parser('--square', help="square func")
square_parser.add_argument("a",type=float,help='number to square')
square_parser.set_defaults(func='square')

args = parser.parse_args()


def add(x,y):
  print x + y

def square(a):
  print a**2

if args.func == '--add':
  add(args.x,args.y)
if args.func == '--square':
  square(args.a)
```

But I am getting error while passing command as `python code.py --add 2 3`

```
invalid choice: '2' (choose from '--add', '--square')
```

Comment: Remove the '--' from the subparser names.  Use just 'add'.  They aren't supposed to look like optionals'' flags.  Also review the docs on using `setdefaults` with subparsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--add` is the form of an `optionals flag`,  `add` is the correct form for a subparser name

```
import argparse
# Create Parser and Subparser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example ArgumentParser")
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', help="commands")

# Make Subparsers
add_parser = subparser.add_parser('add', help="add func")
add_parser.add_argument("x",type=float,help='first number')
add_parser.add_argument("y",type=float,help='second number')
add_parser.set_defaults(func='add')

square_parser = subparser.add_parser('square', help="square func")
square_parser.add_argument("a",type=float,help='number to square')
square_parser.set_defaults(func='square')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

def add(x,y):
  print x + y

def square(a):
  print a**2

if args.func == 'add':    # if args.cmd=='add': also works
  add(args.x,args.y)
if args.func == 'square':
  square(args.a)
```

producing

```
0950:~/mypy$ python stack43557510.py add 2 3
Namespace(cmd='add', func='add', x=2.0, y=3.0)
5.0
```

I added `dest='cmd'` to the `add_subparsers` command, and `print(args)` to give more information.  Note that the subparser name is now available as `args.cmd`.  So you don't need the added `func`.

However the argparse docs do suggest an alternative use of `set_defaults`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

```
add_parser.set_defaults(func=add)
```

With this `args.func` is actually a function object, not just a string name.  So it can be used as

```
args.func(args)
```

Note that I had to change how the functions handle their parameters:

```
def add(args):
    print(args.x + args.y)

def square(args):
    print(args.a**2)

# Create Parser and Subparser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example ArgumentParser")
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', help="commands")

# Make Subparsers
add_parser = subparser.add_parser('add', help="add func")
add_parser.add_argument("x",type=float,help='first number')
add_parser.add_argument("y",type=float,help='second number')
add_parser.set_defaults(func=add)

square_parser = subparser.add_parser('square', help="square func")
square_parser.add_argument("a",type=float,help='number to square')
square_parser.set_defaults(func=square)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

args.func(args)
```

producing

```
1001:~/mypy$ python stack43557510.py add 2 3
Namespace(cmd='add', func=<function add at 0xb73fd224>, x=2.0, y=3.0)
5.0
```